# Javascript: rearrage json output in a specific array format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dictionary, formatting

Another dumb moment for me. Spent hours through for loops, maps, reduce, dictionaries but just can't seem to figure it out. I have a json data that look like this

```
{
  "timeline": [
    {
      "series": "series1",
      "data": [
        {
          "date": "20200713T120000Z",
          "value": 0
        },
        {
          "date": "20200714T120000Z",
          "value": 8
        },
        {
          "date": "20200715T120000Z",
          "value": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "series": "series2",
      "data": [
        {
          "date": "20200713T120000Z",
          "value": 0
        },
        {
          "date": "20200714T120000Z",
          "value": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "series": "series3",
      "data": [
        {
          "date": "20200713T120000Z",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "date": "20200714T120000Z",
          "value": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "series": "series4",
      "data": [
        {
          "date": "20200713T120000Z",
          "value": 2
        },
        {
          "date": "20200714T120000Z",
          "value": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need it in this format

```
[
  {
    date: "20200713T120000Z",
    series1: 0,
    series2: 0,
    series3: 1,
    series4: 2
  },
  {
    date: "20200714T120000Z",
    series1: 8,
    series2: 0,
    series3: 0,
    series4: 4
  }
]
```

Need to do this in JavaScript. Any help/ pointers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an object forgrouping and an array for storing all keys for getting an ordered result with all same keys.

This approach filters all zero values from the result set.

```js
const
    data = { timeline: [{ series: "series1", data: [{ date: "20200713T120000Z", value: 0 }, { date: "20200714T120000Z", value: 8 }, { date: "20200715T120000Z", value: 0 }] }, { series: "series2", data: [{ date: "20200713T120000Z", value: 0 }, { date: "20200714T120000Z", value: 0 }] }, { series: "series3", data: [{ date: "20200713T120000Z", value: 1 }, { date: "20200714T120000Z", value: 0 }] }, { series: "series4", data: [{ date: "20200713T120000Z", value: 2 }, { date: "20200714T120000Z", value: 4 }] }] },
    keys = ['date'],
    result = Object
        .values(data.timeline.reduce((r, { series, data }) => {
            keys.push(series);
            data.forEach(({ date, value }) => {
                if (!value) return;
                if (!r[date]) r[date] = { date };
                r[date][series] = value;
            });
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .map(o => ({ ...Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, 0])), ...o }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is temporary solution for this, you can try this. I'm using `lodash`, so please install it.

```
var _ = require('lodash')

const data = {"timeline": [ { "series": "series1", "data": [ { "date": "20200713T120000Z", "value": 0 },{ "date": "20200714T120000Z", "value": 8 },{ "date": "20200715T120000Z", "value": 0 }] },{ "series": "series2", "data": [ { "date": "20200713T120000Z", "value": 0 },{ "date": "20200714T120000Z", "value": 0 }] },{ "series": "series3", "data": [ { "date": "20200713T120000Z", "value": 1 },{ "date": "20200714T120000Z", "value": 0 }] },{ "series": "series4", "data": [ { "date": "20200713T120000Z", "value": 2 },{ "date": "20200714T120000Z", "value": 4 }] }] }

const t = _.flattenDeep(data.timeline.map(i => i.data.map(d => ({...d, series: i.series}))))

const result = t.reduce((acc, i) => {
    const index = acc.findIndex(a => a.date === i.date)
    if(index !== -1){
        acc[index] = {
            ...acc[index],
            [i.series]: i.value
        }

        
    }else {
        acc.push({
            date: i.date,
            [i.series]: i.value
        })
    }

    return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple `forEach` loops and build an object to track. Then get `Object.values`

```js
const convert = (arr) => {
  const res = {};
  arr.forEach(({ series, data }) =>
    data.forEach(
      ({ date, value }) =>
        (res[date] = { ...(res[date] ?? { date }), [series]: value })
    )
  );
  return Object.values(res);
};

obj = {"timeline": [ { "series": "series1", "data": [ { "date": "20200713T120000Z", "value": 0 },{ "date": "20200714T120000Z", "value": 8 },{ "date": "20200715T120000Z", "value": 0 }] },{ "series": "series2", "data": [ { "date": "20200713T120000Z", "value": 0 },{ "date": "20200714T120000Z", "value": 0 }] },{ "series": "series3", "data": [ { "date": "20200713T120000Z", "value": 1 },{ "date": "20200714T120000Z", "value": 0 }] },{ "series": "series4", "data": [ { "date": "20200713T120000Z", "value": 2 },{ "date": "20200714T120000Z", "value": 4 }] }] }

const res = convert(obj.timeline);
console.log(res)
```